# Issue with subdomain pointing

Tags: dns, subdomain, blogs

Ok so here is is thing. I have a Big Commerce store, and a Fasthost hosting account. The domain is registered at Fasthost. The nameservers are pointed to the Big Commerce store. The store is usuing the main domain name (domain.com)

I am trying to set up a subdomain blog.domain.com and host wordpress on the Fasthost account. I am trying to set up DNS settings in the Big Commerce store to point blog.domain.com back to the Fasthost account where the blog will be. is this possible? How do I set this up correctly?

Answer (score -1):

Usually your DNS provider for should provide you with an interface to manage your DNS records. Once you gain access to such an interface you just need to add an `A` record for `blog.domain.com` to point to your server at the other host. You might also want to add an `NS` record for the *subdomain* to point to the name servers at the other host.

Comment: The thing is i've tried that. I have domain.com name servers pointed to the BC site. The DNS records on the BC site have blog.domain.com pointed back to the hosts IP. I have a subdomain blog.domain.com created under the domain.com on the fasthost account. But would that still work if the main domains namesever is pointing to the BC site?

Comment: @user1904726 did you try adding an NS record to point the _subdomain_ to your FH account

Comment: 33shake.com is registered at Fasthost and the nameservers are set to Big Commerce's.  blog.33shake.com is created as a subdomain under 33shake.com. Fasthost lists their server IP as 88.208.252.208. I have an A record set up on Big commerce for blog.33shake.com pointing to that IP

Comment: @user1904726 I think since your domain is registered with Fasthost you should modify the DNS records with them.